# ReactiveSecurityContextHolder is empty in Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, reactive

I am trying to use the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder with Spring WebFlux. Unfortunately, the SecurityContext is empty :

```
@Configuration
public class Router {

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes(Handler handler) {
        return nest(
                path("/bill"),
                route(
                        GET("/").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), handler::all));
    }

    @Component
    class Handler {

        Mono<ServerResponse> all(ServerRequest request) {

            ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty")))
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .map(Authentication::getName)
                .flatMap(s -> Mono.just("Hi " + s))
                .subscribe(
                        System.out::println,
                        Throwable::printStackTrace,
                        () -> System.out.println("completed without a value")
                );

            return ok().build();
        }

    }

}
```

This code always throws the IllegalStateException.

If I add a subscriberContext like shown [here](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#reactivesecuritycontextholder) :

```
Authentication authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken("admin", "password", "ROLE_ADMIN");

ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty")))
        .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
        .map(Authentication::getName)
        .flatMap(s -> Mono.just("Hi " + s))
        .subscriberContext(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
        .subscribe(
                System.out::println,
                Throwable::printStackTrace,
                () -> System.out.println("completed without a value")
        );
```

It works fine and print "Hi admin". But that's not the point, the article says "In a WebFlux application the `subscriberContext` is automatically setup using `ReactorContextWebFilter`". So I should be able to fetch the logged user.

I have this configuration :

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
            .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("password")
            .roles("USER")
            .build();

        UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN")
            .build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user, admin);
    }

}
```

Am I missing something here ? If I put breakpoints in ReactorContextWebFilter, I can see that it is correctly called before each request. But my ReactiveSecurityContextHolder is always empty...

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I ended up using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest#principal`, but I would like to use `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` too

Comment: Nope, I used the "classic" notation with @Controller annotations and I injected the Principal object in my methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to return the stream in which you want to access *ReactiveSecurityContextHolder*. You're not allowed to subscribe within another stream **OR** you have to do the Reactor context switch manually.

```
@Component
class Handler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> all(ServerRequest request) {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("ReactiveSecurityContext is empty")))
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .map(Authentication::getName)
                .flatMap(s -> Mono.just("Hi " + s))
                .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.println("completed without value: " + s))
                .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.ok().build());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I access ReactiveSecurityContextHolder within WebFluxTagsContributor.httpRequestTags? The method is not returning a publisher

Comment: Can you please explain more about the theoretical description which you have mentioned in the title of your answer.

Comment: OK, in a traditional Servlet based WebApp the SecurityContext is hold in a ThreadLoacal. If you don't create new Threads you can access the Security Context, but if you want to access the SecurityContext from another Thread, you have to manually "move" / copy the SecutiryContext from your current Thread to the new one.

The same applies for Reactive WebApps, but a bit different. When you start/subscribe a new Stream, it's the same as creating a new Thread in a Servlet WebApp. Then you have to manually "move" / copy the SecurityContext to the new Stream/Subscription.

Comment: Could you please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062475/reactivesecuritycontextholder-returns-null-in-case-of-blocking-operations

Comment: How do you do the Reactor context switch manually ?