# How to access JWT in Spring Webflux in ReactiveSecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

How do I access the JTW token?
.block() throws exception and all other methods dont seem to work.

Here is how I normaly do it in:

```
@Bean("CurrentUser")
public Supplier<JwtAuthenticationToken> currentUser() {
    return () -> (JwtAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}
```

Then I pass it in the constructor:

```
@Qualifier("CurrentUser") Supplier<JwtAuthenticationToken> currentUserSupplier
```

And here is a use case:

```
currentUserSupplier.get().getTokenAttributes().get(USER_MAIN_ID_TOKEN)
```

I am trying to do the same with *ReactiveSecurityContextHolder* but its proving imposible.

I have tried the solutions in this questions. They all return either nothing or null.

[ReactiveSecurityContextHolder is empty in Spring WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905505/reactivesecuritycontextholder-is-empty-in-spring-webflux)

[How to get claims from jwt token in spring webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859061/how-to-get-claims-from-jwt-token-in-spring-webflux)

[block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking error when calling bodyToMono AFTER exchange()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449889/block-blockfirst-blocklast-are-blocking-error-when-calling-bodytomono-afte)

[How to get String from Mono<String> in reactive java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47179937/how-to-get-string-from-monostring-in-reactive-java)

Maybe It is simply not possible to get it in a "blocking manner" since its a reactive framework. Can anybody give any further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I got it to do what I wanted but in the reactive way. Just had to refactor a bunch of code. Guess I need to learn how to think in reactive ways.

However if someone needs a way to get a claim in a non reactive way, **here is a hacky way I found**. Assuming you are in controll of the client that is calling your service just send the claims you want to access in the request. Ofcourse this is not good because someone could send false information. But to solve that all you have to so Is to compare them with your jwt token (in a reactive way xD). In the security filter chain add a custom filter that will make this verification. Here is an implementation:

*In this example I want to get the value "mainId" from the token so I just send it in the path variable, and then in the security filter just for x path I check if the value sent in the path variable is the same as the one in the token, if so I know I can use it, if not the request is not correct and I return a 403*

Declare path to run filter on:

```
private final ServerWebExchangeMatcher pathMatcher = ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/notification/getEvents/**");
```

Security filter chain:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(authorize -> {
                try {
                    authorize.anyExchange().authenticated()
                            .and()
                            .addFilterAt(this::filter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHORIZATION);;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .oauth2ResourceServer(
                    oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(getJwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver()));

    http.headers()
            .xssProtection()
            .disable()
            .frameOptions();

    return http.build();
```

Your filter:

```
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return pathMatcher.matches(exchange)
            .flatMap(matchResult -> {
                if (matchResult.isMatch()) {
                    return checkClaim(exchange);
                } else {
                    return chain.filter(exchange);
                }
            });
}
```

Check the claim:

```
   private Mono<Void> checkClaim(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .flatMap(authentication -> {
                    if (authentication instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
                        JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthenticationToken = (JwtAuthenticationToken) authentication;
                        String pathVariableMainId = getMainIdFromExchange(exchange);
                        if (jwtAuthenticationToken.getTokenAttributes().containsKey("mainId")) {
                            String claimMainId = jwtAuthenticationToken.getTokenAttributes().get("mainId").toString();
                            if (pathVariableMainId.equals(claimMainId)) {
                                return Mono.empty(); // Authorized
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return Mono.error(new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied"));
                });
    }
```

Get the main Id from the path variable:

```
public String getMainIdFromExchange(ServerWebExchange exchange ){
    String path = exchange.getRequest().getPath().value();
    UriTemplate uriTemplate = new UriTemplate("/notification/getEvents/{mainId}");
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters = uriTemplate.match(path); //extract values form template

    return parameters.get("mainId");
}
```

I know this is extremly hacky, but it works. :)

If anybody knows of a better way please add a response :)